# How can I remove a non-load bearing wall in my basement?

Tags: basement, remodeling

I have two small rooms in basement. I want to remove the common wall between the two and covert the resulting big room into a home theater.

What is the best way to remove the studs, wiring, etc.?

Comment: You are going to have to separate these into 3 questions.  And for the first question we need more information.  Basement layout, what the plumbing is for, what the wiring is for.

Comment: DMoore,Thanks for your comments. I did not understand your question about plumbing. The wiring is related to the wall power socket on this wall that I plan to remove. Also I have TV cable and telephone connections/sockets on this wall

Comment: You had mentioned that there were pipes in the wall. I believe that @DMoore is connecting "pipes" to "plumbing". However it is really hard to tell because you did not specify if these pipes were electrical conduits, drain pipes, water supply pipes or heating pipes.

Comment: You seemed to be asking three different; but related, questions. I've edited the question to ask a single question, as that works better with the format of the site. Feel free to ask more questions using the Ask Question button.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to be careful about removing that wall. I hope there are three rooms in the basement because this sounds load bearing. Is the wall bisecting the basement? If it is a normal non-load bearing wall, my advice is to just go for it.

Find the circuit connected to the wires in the wall, turn it off at the breaker, and cut them out of they way. After you cut them, cap each of the wires keeping them separate and put them into a temporary junction box.

For the Studs, the easiest way to remove them is cutting the nails at the bottom of each one with a reciprocating saw. If you don't have one, beat them out of the way. My guess is that it is old lumber and you have plenty of heavy nails to deal with so "beating them" may be back breaking. Find a friend who has one or pay the neighbor kid a few dollars an hour.

Good luck with the carpet...too many options here.

And save that old lumber. That is good stuff. You just cant use it with new lumber because it is too thick.

Comment: StackExchange asks that you include links to personal sites in your user profile, not as a signature to posts here. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Your answer seems to assume that this is a very old house.. I'm not sure how you made the jump to assuming that it's old lumber, or that if there are three rooms the wall is not load bearing. In Canada at least, it's very rare for there to be any load bearing walls in the basement: any house built in the past 40 years likely has jack posts and beams (except perhaps for the walls supporting the stairs).